# Linux Mint Slow boot time

Tags: linux-mint

I'm a noob to Linux Mint OS. my laptop was booting very fast when i installed mint. but now after about 1 week of usage its taking long time to boot up my laptop.

Can you guys give any suggestion to get back my boot up speed?

here is my

systemd-analyze blame

```
     20.274s systemd-journal-flush.service
     17.938s dev-sda2.device
     11.544s keyboard-setup.service
     11.365s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      9.939s systemd-sysctl.service
      7.188s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      7.085s networkd-dispatcher.service
      6.852s snapd.service
      5.742s ubuntu-system-adjustments.service
      5.347s NetworkManager.service
      3.615s udisks2.service
      2.468s thermald.service
      2.136s gpu-manager.service
      2.066s systemd-random-seed.service
      2.048s ModemManager.service
      1.981s accounts-daemon.service
      1.768s dev-loop2.device
      1.412s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.345s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      1.128s avahi-daemon.service
      1.043s dev-loop1.device
      1.040s dev-loop0.device
      1.034s grub-common.service
       717ms apparmor.service
       706ms wpa_supplicant.service
       699ms lightdm.service
       695ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
       568ms systemd-udevd.service
       531ms dns-clean.service
       528ms swapfile.swap
       495ms speech-dispatcher.service
       485ms pppd-dns.service
       481ms lm-sensors.service
       450ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
       450ms systemd-logind.service
       439ms polkit.service
       384ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       352ms networking.service
       349ms ufw.service
       325ms systemd-journald.service
       312ms packagekit.service
       276ms blk-availability.service
       263ms systemd-resolved.service
       263ms qemu-kvm.service
       261ms plymouth-read-write.service
       249ms rsyslog.service
       249ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       231ms virtualbox.service
       212ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       211ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-729B\x2d4E51.service
       200ms boot-efi.mount
       200ms dev-hugepages.mount
       197ms upower.service
       195ms snap-core-5897.mount
       170ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       145ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       118ms setvtrgb.service
        96ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        91ms user@1000.service
        90ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        83ms dev-mqueue.mount
        67ms colord.service
        59ms apport.service
        48ms snap-core-5742.mount
        38ms snap-anbox-158.mount
        36ms alsa-restore.service
        35ms snapd.seeded.service
        32ms hddtemp.service
        23ms plymouth-start.service
        22ms kerneloops.service
        19ms snapd.socket
        15ms motd-news.service
        10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         9ms systemd-rfkill.service
         9ms ureadahead-stop.service
         8ms console-setup.service
         7ms rtkit-daemon.service
         5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         3ms openvpn.service
```

will it help to disable some of this services?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling unnecessary services will help improve boot time, but if you are not sure what the services do, then you probably run the risk of not booting at all if you start disabling them willy-nilly.

Have you measured the boot time now versus what it was? What are the specs of your system? There are  a lot of factors that could affect boot time, and you haven't yet provided a lot of details.